# Pass a PHP object for use in an external JS script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm grabbing some information out of a database and passing it to some JavaScript using `json_encode()`. The line: `var row_data = <?php echo $month_stats ?>;` is dumping the object into the JS.

But now I want to abstract my JS into an external file, so suddenly I can't just `echo` the contents of the object into the JS since PHP won't have any presence there.

So I need to somehow (via AJAX?) send the PHP object `$month_stats` directly to the JS so that it can use the information independently of PHP, but I'm not sure how this is implemented. Any pointers?

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

$month_stats = generate_monthly_count_stats($conn);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var row_data = <?php echo $month_stats ?>;
    console.log(row_data);

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you move the javascript to external files, you could still leave those values within your head section as a global variable (hopefully within a namespace). and when you other javascript code just starts after the document is ready, you should have no need for ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply echo the variable and access it in an external file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var row_data = <?php echo $month_stats ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

row_data is now a global variable, so you can access it in the external.js. However it is better to add it to a namespace if you have lots of other variables..

Answer (score 1):

When you put the JS into an external file, make it a function with one parameter.

In your .js file:

```
function logRowData(var1)
{
    console.log(var1);
}
```

In your .php file:

```
<head>
<?php
    include(filename.js);
?>
</head>
```

To log the stats, you can call in the php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    logRowData($month_stats)
</script>
```

[More info on JS Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can create some javascripn function in .js file

```
myFunction(obj) {
    console.log(obj);
}
```

in your php file you can do that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
myFunction(<?php echo $month_stats ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the variable `row_data` in your included Javascript file, it should work, as you are declaring that in the global scope.  Here's one article for reference: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable